# Cypress receives 401 in login page with Clerk authentication

Tags: cypress, clerk

I have a website in which the login is done with [Clerk](https://clerk.com/). When trying to test it with Cypress, I face the issue that my login page returns 401.

When testing it in an incognito window, I see that right after the 401, it does another request which then gets redirected and succeeds.

[image: 401 failure]

The response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
content-type: text/html
x-clerk-auth-reason: uat-missing
x-clerk-auth-status: interstitial
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 23:34:13 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for the `x-clerk-auth-reason: uat-missing` response header, I haven't found anything in Google or the Clerk.com docs.

Then, checking further requests, I saw that they include the cookie `__client_uat=0`, so I have tried it, and it works! Now I am making my request:

```js
cy.visit('/my-login-page', {
  headers: {
    'Cookie': '__client_uat=0'
  }
});
```

I guess this is just the case for Clerk development applications.

I hope this helps somebody in the future! :)

Answer (score 0):

Before navigating to the login page, ensure you set the necessary cookie by utilizing cy.setCookie(). After the cookie is set,you can visit the login page:

```
  cy.setCookie('__client_uat', '0').then(() => {
  cy.visit("/login", { failOnStatusCode: false });
});
```

Regarding to Clerk documentation, during test , there's a possibility of encountering rate limits. Instead, sign in once and then re-use the same session for multiple tests. first Create your sign in custom command, then use it into beforeEach and cy.session. here is the clerk documentation for testing [Testing with cypress and Clerk](https://clerk.com/docs/testing/cypress)

```
    describe("Authenticate using Clerk", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.session('signed-in', () => {
      cy.signIn();
    });
  });
});
```